# Проблема при парсинге сайта, с помощью bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzL9R.jpg  вот картинка кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите 2 часа голову ломаю

Comment: приведите в вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) в виде текста, а не картинкой и полный `error traceback` или конкретное описание проблемы (если речь идет о логической ошибке).

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос...

```
url = 'https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

pages = int(soup.find('a', {'data-cy':'page-link-last'}).find('span').contents[0])

urls = [f'{url}?page={p}' for p in range(1, pages+1)]
```

результат:

```
In [95]: urls
Out[95]:
['https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/?page=1',
 'https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/?page=2',
 'https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/?page=3',
 'https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/?page=4',
 'https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/?page=5',
 'https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/?page=6',
 'https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/?page=7',
 'https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/?page=8',
 'https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/?page=9',
 'https://www.olx.ua/pol/q-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/?page=10']
```